# Star Team find modified files for a project

Tags: starteam

We recently switched from clear case to star team. In clear case, we had a feature that for one project, we could select option 'Find Checkouts' which would show all the files checked out.
For starteam, is it possible to know all modified files for a particular project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the toolbar there is a button with a tooltip of "All descendants."  Enable it.  To the left of that is a dropdown.  Choose "<All Files By Status And Folder Path>."  In the folder area on the left, select your root directory.  That will group all files in the working tree by current, not in view, modified, etc.

Comment: Awesome!  I have been using ST for nearly a year, and when I would have to sort it by name, then wanted to go back to seeing the modified ones, i would close the program and turn it back on...  Thanks!